# tensorflow install on sierra

Tags: python, tensorflow, macos-sierra

Thanks for your help in advance, I am aware that I have very limited experience in programming so please be gracious and take the considerate approach ('instead of you have no business doing this' approach).
I am trying to install tensorflow. This is my first time using python (I have Anaconda installed and got iJupyter Notebooks to work). I did manage to get tensorflow running in R (which I am somewhat proficient in). However when installing tensorflow using the Anaconda instructions I get this error:

```
    Exception:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 329, in clobber
os.utime(destfile, (st.st_atime, st.st_mtime))

    OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy_install.py'
```

I found a few suggestions for pip installs but did not know if those were relevant since I used the conda option.
Python 2.7
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 // MacBook Pro 15inch
If you have a response for novices - that would be great.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like Anaconda is in your `PATH` because your system python is getting used there. I recommend continuing to try to use Anaconda to do what you want to do and to create a virtual environment using Anaconda.

Where did you install it (for all users or just yourself)?

Look at the result of this:

```
$ which conda
```

If you get an answer about `no conda`, then you need to add it to your PATH. Find the install location for `anaconda` and do this:

```
$ export PATH=ANACONDA_LOCATION/bin:$PATH
```

where `ANACONDA_LOCATION` is the installed location.

Next, create an environment:

```
$ conda create -n myenv
```

If you get permissions errors here, then your user will need write access to this directory:

```
$ ls -l ANACONDA_LOCATION/envs
```

This is why it's usually a fine idea to just install Anaconda for your user instead of all users.

After that, activate your environment:

```
$ source activate myenv
```

Finally, with an activated environment and `conda` in your `PATH`, you should be able to install things:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

---

**Future Use**

Whenever you want to use `tensorflow` in the future, you will have to activate this environment where it has been installed:

```
$ source activate myenv
```